# Auto-create a list of conjectures from given documents

Tags: cross-referencing, environments

I have three mathematical documents.

I want to auto-create fourth document, which should show all conjectures and problems from the first three documents. I mean that the following should be auto-copied to the fourth document:

```
\begin{conjecture}
...
\end{conjecture}

\begin{question}
...
\end{question}
```

How to create this (fourth) document?

Comment: Well, it would be nice if you would show us how the `conjectures` where done, perhaps it's possible to use the `xr` package to include labels etc.

Comment: answers package https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/answers

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clipboard